# Is this IPTables rule the same as a universal whitelist?

Tags: iptables

I am a little shaky on how the state module works. I was just curious if the below line is a universal white list i.e. equivelent to `iptables -A INPUT -j ACCEPT`.

```
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only other possibility for state is INVALID, so while your rule is not semantically a universal whitelist, it is practically equivalent for all ordinary purposes.